# Windows Drive Share Issue

Tags: windows, network-shares, nas

I set up an NAS system today and it works like a charm on my LAN. I'm having trouble with making it accessible through the internet.

- The NAS has a web management system which I hooked up to a dynamic dns service. I can access the web interface through the internet which means the DNS settings are correct.
- Locally I can access the share both using `\\localip` and `\\myserver.mytld`
- When I try accessing it from a computer on a different network using `\\myserver.mytld` I get

  Your computer appears to be correctly configured but the device or resource (myserver.mytld) is not responding.
- I am not using LDAP nor AD
- I opened ports 88 for kerberos, 445 for smb and 135-139 (udp and tcp for all) but it doesn't work.
- All client computers are running Windows 8.1
- All client computers have networking sharing/discovery/everything in advanced sharing settings enabled
- All client computers have been tested with firewall temporarily suspended
- I don't and don't want to use a VPN or proxy.
- The router that the NAS is behind does not appear to have any firewall functionalities.
- I am using a QNAP TS-420

Comment: in the end I gave up and used a VPN